# I have DDR3 10600E ram and i don't know if it will run with my 10600 compatible motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, desktop-computer

I've got four 1 gb sticks of DDR3 PC3-10600E and my question is: Will it run on my future motherboard or will i have to get some new ones? These sticks were pulled out of a mac pro that is why i'm concerned. My motherboard is Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD3H-BK and a link here http://www.komputronik.pl/product/259165/Elektronika/Cz%C4%99%C5%9Bci_PC/Gigabyte_GA_Z97X_UD3H_BK.html (sorry for polish site)

edit: i don't want the ecc function to work, i just want the ram to work.

Answer (score 0):

10600E RAM looks like it is mostly used in laptops. That motherboard is for desktops. I'm not sure if 10600E is *only* used in laptops but those are the only results I have found so far. To be sure, you would need to know if it is 240-pin or 204-pin RAM. 240-pin is used in desktops and 204-pin is used in laptops.

Comment: It looks like a desktop ram to me. How would i check it? I have only the stick, not the box. There is no mention of a number 204 or 240.

Comment: Is there a label on the RAM that can give you any more information? If you know the company of the RAM maybe you could google and find the model.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Micron-MT9JSF12872AZ-1G4F1-DDR3-1333-PC3-10600-Unbuffered/dp/B008KO6LVA this is it

Comment: On the Gigabyte [specifications page](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4979#sp) for that motherboard, it says `4. Support for non-ECC memory modules`. I know you said you don't want the ECC to work, but I'm not sure if the motherboard can even support the module.

Comment: Ok, then it's going to be a wild guess. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

No, those memory modules will not work with that motherboard.  They are ECC modules and that motherboard does not support ECC.  It is not a function that can be turned on or off.

Answer (score -1):

most Mac Pros Works on Xeon and Intel X series CPU and support ECC memory. Z97 motherboards don't support ECC memory, nor CPUs that support ECC memory so they will not work on that board. 10600E is a server specific unbuffered ECC memory.

Comment: Welcome. We are always happy to see spelling correct (which includes capitals) and a source to the information.